# Preventing blue background on selecting a cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove the selection color that appears when I touch a cell in my tableview.

In IB there is a "shows selection" checkbox that does nothing and it seems from what I can gather that it is just a bug in IB.

But then there is the 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
that I can set to each cell.

This also does nothing, so this is where I am stuck, all documentation say that if I set this property it should not appear but it does.

I push another UIViewController on a UINavigationController, and when I go back to the view in question, the blue background on the cell is stuck until I touch another one.

The only thing special is that I instantiate this UITableViewController with the help of storyboard and I use prototype cells. Then I put it inside a UIScrollView to have horizontal paging between multiple UITableViewControllers. There is no way to access the navigation controller when I do this so I pass the UINavigationController along to the UITableView.

Sorry that I can't make the keywords appear as code, it says I should press the tab key then type a $ but that moves my cursor to tags.

Comment: It seems if I set selection to none on my prototype cell in IB it works.

So just as a warning to set selection style on a prototype cell apparently does nothing.

I cannot answer my own question for 7 hours but this is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the style on the prototype cell in IB. Many things are wierd about prototype cells.

Answer (score 3):

You might try to set the `selectedBackgroundView` of your cell like this :

```
customCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

In the delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Yes this is what I would have tried but if I change it on the prototype cell in IB it propagates and works mysteriously :)

Answer (score 1):

From code you can use (for example for grey):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

And put this at:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In your ViewController.

Comment: I know, that did not work, I had to change it in IB on the prototype cell to get it to work :/